# Getting "Permission denied" page in the admin, while user has permission

Tags: python, django, permissions

I've got some issue with user permissions in Django. I added some permissions for the `Magasin` model as shown below:

```
add_magasin=Permission.objects.get(codename="add_magasin")
change_magasin=Permission.objects.get(codename="change_magasin")
delete_magasin=Permission.objects.get(codename="delete_magasin")
user.user_permissions.add(add_magasin)
user.user_permissions.add(change_magasin)
user.user_permissions.add(delete_magasin)
user.save()
```

<s>then when I check the permission I get:</s>

```
In [100]: user.has_perm(delete_magasin)
Out[100]: False

In [101]: user.has_perm(add_magasin)
Out[101]: False

In [102]: user.has_perm(change_magasin)
Out[102]: False
```

and in the admin, connected with the same user, I can add a Magasin instance, but not delete one ("Permission denied"). I can't even delete a Magasin instance with the superuser.

I'm using Django 1.3 and I'm not using any external permission-related app...

**EDIT: sql queries**

```
mysql> select * from django_content_type;
+----+-----------------------+--------------+------------------+
| id | name                  | app_label    | model            |
+----+-----------------------+--------------+------------------+
***more stuff***
|  9 | magasin               | securite_v2  | magasin          |
***more stuff***


mysql> select * from auth_permission;
+----+----------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------------+
| id | name                             | content_type_id | codename                |
+----+----------------------------------+-----------------+-------------------------+
***more stuff***
| 25 | Can add magasin                  |               9 | add_magasin             |
| 26 | Can change magasin               |               9 | change_magasin          |
| 27 | Can delete magasin               |               9 | delete_magasin          |
***more stuff***


mysql> select * from auth_user where id=135;
+-----+---------------+------------+-----------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id  | username      | first_name | last_name | email                         | password                                            | is_staff | is_active | is_superuser | last_login          | date_joined         |
+-----+---------------+------------+-----------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 135 | admingrandest |            |           | admingrandest@xxx.com | sha1$14f21$02a50f37be16f27aba3f677618b663edfb0ce5a7 |        1 |         1 |            0 | 2012-06-25 11:16:35 | 2012-06-22 16:42:46 |
+-----+---------------+------------+-----------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+


mysql> select * from auth_user_user_permissions;
+----+---------+---------------+
| id | user_id | permission_id |
+----+---------+---------------+
|  1 |     135 |            25 |
|  2 |     135 |            26 |
|  3 |     135 |            27 |
***more stuff***
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you forgot a `user.save()` somewhere.

Comment: I do save the user (I edited the question)...

Comment: You shouldn't need to save the user anyway, it's a ManyToMany relationship so the relevant entities are saved on `add`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it has to do with file permissions, not Django user permissions.

Comment: What should be the permissions?

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of [`User.has_perm()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm) have to be a string in `<app label>.<permission codename>` format. In you're code you're passing `Permission` instance as first argument, which get's evaluated to `<app_label> | <content_type> | <name>`, so `has_perm` will always return `False`.

Instead use `user.has_perm("<yourapp>.delete_magasin")`

Comment: But if I set the permission properly, I should be able to delete my instance from the admin, right? And why the superuser wouldn't be able to delete it?

Comment: Are you getting an error/exception or just on "delete" buttons?

Comment: In admin, on delete button, I get a page "Permission denied".

Comment: Do you have `ContentType` entries generated for the models you're trying to access?

Comment: Using `user.has_perm("<yourapp>.delete_magasin")`, I get True for add/change/delete Magasin instance. The problem is that on the admin, I still get a "permission denied". Any idea?