# How to delete an object with a given user in Django's shell?

Tags: django, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting “Permission denied” page in the admin, while user has permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186531/getting-permission-denied-page-in-the-admin-while-user-has-permission)

I've got [some issues with permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186531/getting-permission-denied-page-in-the-admin-while-user-has-permission), so I'd like to see what's going from the shell.

Can I start the shell with a given user?

Or can I delete an object from the shell, as if I was connected to the admin with a given user?

Basically, how can I see why I'm getting a page with "Permission denied" when trying to delete an object when the user actually has the permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Permissions are only enforced by your business logic, so using normal Django ORM syntax in the shell will completely bypass any restrictions.

Finding the element will depend on how it is related to User, but assuming a ForeignKey called `user`:

```
my_obj = MyObject.objects.filter(user__username='whatever')
```

Comment: My question was not clear: I want to delete an object from the shell, as if I was connected with a given user to the admin.

Comment: So what is wrong with my answer then? If you have a user with username `whatever`, then using my code will allow you to get the relevant object and delete it.

Comment: My model has no field `user`. What I want to achieve in the shell is like loging in in the admin with different user and try to delete an object.

Comment: There is no concept of performing a query "as" a particular user in Django.  The admin application itself (and any additional application code you write) is what enforces permissions.